# Function/filter/action to replace product title for woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have this function

```
function my_product_title($title, $id)
    {
if(in_the_loop() && is_product())
{
    return '<span class="border">FooBar</span>';
}
return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'my_product_title', 5, 2);
```

and it can replace the product title with `return '<span class="border">FooBar</span>';`.

I also have a custom script in "mycustomtitle.php" that can modify the products titles and my script can echo that modified title as `$mycustomtitle`

I want to replace the original product title with my `$mycustomtitle` without changing anything in the core files.

I've tried to just change `return '<span class="border">FooBar</span>';` to `$mycustomtitle` but it only removes the original title and gives no output at all...

Thanks!

**UPDATE 2016-10-20 With custom code:**

```
<?php

include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/plugins/seo-controlpanel/seo-engine/explode.php';

$tit1 = $boomprint[array_rand($boomprint)].' '.file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/plugins/seo-controlpanel/write-to/product-title-h1.php'); 

$tit2 = $boomprint[array_rand($boomprint)].' '.file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/plugins/seo-controlpanel/write-to/product-title-h1.php');

$title_keys = array($tit1,$tit2);
$title_key11 = $title_keys[array_rand($title_keys)];

if(!function_exists(spin11)){
function spin11($string11) {
    while(true) {
        if(!preg_match_all('/({([^\{]*?)\})/', $string11, $matches))
            break;
        foreach($matches[2] as $i => $match) {
            $parts = explode('|', $match);
            $string11 = str_replace_once11($matches[0][$i], $parts[mt_rand(0, count($parts)-1)], $string11);
        }
    }
    return $string11;
}
}
if(!function_exists(str_replace_once11)){
function str_replace_once11($from,$to,$str)
{
    $str = explode($from,$str,2);
    return $str[0].$to.$str[1];
}  
$title_id11  = get_the_ID();
$fileLocation11 = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . '/wp-content/plugins/seo-controlpanel/seo-cache/product-title-h1/'.$title_id11.'.txt';
if(!file_exists($fileLocation11)){
$file11 = fopen($fileLocation11,"w");
$content11 = spin11($title_key11);
fwrite($file11,$content11);
fclose($file11);
}
if(file_exists($fileLocation11)){
$myFile11 = $fileLocation11;
$fh11 = fopen($myFile11, 'r');
$theData11 = fread($fh11, filesize($myFile11));
fclose($fh11);
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert your custom code in your function.

```
function my_product_title($title, $id) {
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/plugins/seo-controlpanel/seo-engine/explode.php';

    $tit1 = $boomprint[array_rand($boomprint)].' '.file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/plugins/seo-controlpanel/write-to/product-title-h1.php'); 

    $tit2 = $boomprint[array_rand($boomprint)].' '.file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/plugins/seo-controlpanel/write-to/product-title-h1.php');

    $title_keys = array($tit1,$tit2);
    $title_key11 = $title_keys[array_rand($title_keys)];

    if(!function_exists(spin11)){
        function spin11($string11) {
            while(true) {
                if(!preg_match_all('/({([^\{]*?)\})/', $string11, $matches))
                    break;
                foreach($matches[2] as $i => $match) {
                    $parts = explode('|', $match);
                    $string11 = str_replace_once11($matches[0][$i], $parts[mt_rand(0, count($parts)-1)], $string11);
                }
            }
            return $string11;
        }
    }
    if(!function_exists(str_replace_once11)){
        function str_replace_once11($from,$to,$str)
        {
            $str = explode($from,$str,2);
            return $str[0].$to.$str[1];
        }  
        $title_id11  = get_the_ID();
        $fileLocation11 = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . '/wp-content/plugins/seo-controlpanel/seo-cache/product-title-h1/'.$title_id11.'.txt';
        if(!file_exists($fileLocation11)){
            $file11 = fopen($fileLocation11,"w");
            $content11 = spin11($title_key11);
            fwrite($file11,$content11);
            fclose($file11);
        }
        if(file_exists($fileLocation11)){
            $myFile11 = $fileLocation11;
            $fh11 = fopen($myFile11, 'r');
            $theData11 = fread($fh11, filesize($myFile11));
            fclose($fh11);
        }
    }
    if(in_the_loop() && is_product()) {
        return $theData11;
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'my_product_title', 5, 2);
```

Comment: Ok, if i declare some text then it replaces the original title. But i want to replace the title with a variable from another .php file. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you provide your custom code? So, I give you perfect answer.

Comment: I've updated my question with the code. Just let me know if you need something else. Thanks:)

Comment: Are you wish to download any file?

Comment: No, my script writes some text to a file `$fileLocation11 = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . '/wp-content/plugins/seo-controlpanel/seo-cache/product-title-h1/'.$title_id11.'.txt';
` and i want to replace the products title (H1) with that content.

Comment: I edit my answer. Please, see that. If you need something else then tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Is $mycustomtitle global variable or it is defined inside another function/method/class?
If it is global variable this may help:

```
function my_product_title($title, $id)
{
      global $mycustomtitle;
      if(in_the_loop() && is_product())
      {
        return $mycustomtitle;
      }
      return $title;
}
```

Comment: Here's the code in the file (the real name of the variable is `$theData11`)

Comment: Sorry for adding an answer, but the code included too many characters to match the criteria for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/plugins/seo-controlpanel/seo-engine/explode.php';

$tit1 = $boomprint[array_rand($boomprint)].' '.file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/plugins/seo-controlpanel/write-to/product-title-h1.php'); 

$tit2 = $boomprint[array_rand($boomprint)].' '.file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/plugins/seo-controlpanel/write-to/product-title-h1.php');

$title_keys = array($tit1,$tit2);
$title_key11 = $title_keys[array_rand($title_keys)];

if(!function_exists(spin11)){
function spin11($string11) {
    while(true) {
        if(!preg_match_all('/({([^\{]*?)\})/', $string11, $matches))
            break;
        foreach($matches[2] as $i => $match) {
            $parts = explode('|', $match);
            $string11 = str_replace_once11($matches[0][$i], $parts[mt_rand(0, count($parts)-1)], $string11);
        }
    }
    return $string11;
}
}
if(!function_exists(str_replace_once11)){
function str_replace_once11($from,$to,$str)
{
    $str = explode($from,$str,2);
    return $str[0].$to.$str[1];
}  
$title_id11  = get_the_ID();
$fileLocation11 = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . '/wp-content/plugins/seo-controlpanel/seo-cache/product-title-h1/'.$title_id11.'.txt';
if(!file_exists($fileLocation11)){
$file11 = fopen($fileLocation11,"w");
$content11 = spin11($title_key11);
fwrite($file11,$content11);
fclose($file11);
}
if(file_exists($fileLocation11)){
$myFile11 = $fileLocation11;
$fh11 = fopen($myFile11, 'r');
$theData11 = fread($fh11, filesize($myFile11));
fclose($fh11);
}
}
//echo $theData11;
?>
```